# Geogebra plot range

Tags: geogebra

I created this plot through the GeoGebra spreadsheet:

[image]

I would be interested in getting the same plot, but only in range between the first (1;3) and the last (3;4.5) point. How can I do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Ok  this is my firs answer  , you can type that in the input line below   : `If(1 < x < 3, f(x))`
where `f(x)` is your function

Comment: Another method is write 

Function( f(x),x,1,3 )

Answer (score 0):

For example, for `f(x) = x^2`, you can input like this: `x² / (x < -1 ∨ x > 1)`

`(x < -1 ∨ x > 1)` is a boolean value, `True == 1`, and `False == 0`. `0` as a denominator is meaningless, and this can be used to limit the display range in Geogebra.

Comment: This does not answer the poster's question. How would you limit the range?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Got it. I've updated the answer to be more complete.